# need file extension in url to access template

Tags: templating, routes, routing

I've got a structure setup, and one of the entries under it is called "Our people" at the top level, in the "About" structure. So the url would look like this: `/about/our-people`.

I have a template setup at: `craft/templates/about/our-people.html`

When browsing `/about/our-people` it does not route there, though `/about/our-people.html` works fine.

In my general config I have `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true` set.
Only weird thing I have is a "Single" entry is setup to deal with the top level "about" page viewable at `/about`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: In your about structure settings, what do you have in the Entry Template box?

Comment: "about/_entry" though I thought this could be overwritten with a specific file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for how Craft picks a template is [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing). Two of the relevant steps are:

> 4. **Is it an entry/category request?**
>      If the URI matches an entry’s or category’s URI, the section’s/category group’s template will get loaded, and the matched element will be made available to the template via a pre-populated entry or category variable.

and

> 6. **Does the URI match a template?**
>      Finally, Craft will see if the URI is a valid template path. If it is, it will return the matched template.

`/about/our-people` matches #4, and you get the `about/_entry.html` template. `/about/our-people.html` matches #6, so you get the `about/our-people.html` template.

The important thing is that Craft uses the **first** rule that matches.

Comment: Cheers Marion, Just incase others don't quite understand this... The fix is to route the template through `about/_entry.html`.

Comment: Hi @joe could you show an example of how to route the template through `about/_entry.html` please?